# Reading a number from stdin in C

Tags: c, validation, input, stream, flush

I have a function to get a number from `stdin` in C.

```
int io_get_num(const char *q, const size_t min, const size_t max, int * num)
{ /* Get a number from the command line */
    int ret = 0;

    do {
        printf(q);
        ret = scanf(" %d", num);
        if (ret == EOF)
            return EOF;
        else if (ret == 0)
            printf("Please provide a valid number ..\n%s", q);
        else if (*num > max || *num < min)
            printf("Number must be smaller than %u and larger than %u\n%s", (unsigned int)max+1, (unsigned int)min-1, q);
        else
            break;
        /* Flushing stdin */
        int ch;
        while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n' );
    } while (1);

    return ret;
}
```

It works fine in the first loop run, and after that (I noticed when breaking with gdb) the loop runs twice except that it doesn't wait for my input or check any conditions (that probably has something to do with flushing the stream) ..

What can I do about that issue ?

Comment: Why are you flushing the input exactly? What are you expecting this code to do?

Comment: Firstly, what is the purpose of that space in `" %d"` in `scanf`? It is completely redundant there. Secondly, I don't see any evidence of your cycle iterating twice after incorrect input. For some reason you print `q` again after the error message, which might create an *illusion* of the cycle iterating twice, while in reality it does not happen. Thirdly, your idea to print the lower end range as `(unsigned int)min-1` will produce a very strange (from the user's point of view) output if `min` is zero. Fourthly, it is not clear what exactly you are trying to "flush" from the input here and why.

Comment: what is `stream`?. i think it should be `stdin`

Comment: @Rustam: Corrected that.

Comment: @AndreyT: Firstly, why is `" %d"` redundant ? It is supposed to force `scanf` to ignore white-space. Secondly, I stated that I traced the code flow with gcc, so I'm absolutely sure it ran twice. Thirdly, you're right, I updated the code above. Fourthly, this behavior tries to implement the non-standard function `fflush`. It tries to remove user-space buffered data that were not caught by scanf (in case the user did not provide valid input to substitute `" %d". Try removing it to see what happens ..

Comment: @Amr Ayman: `%d` already skips any leading whitespace by itself. All `scanf` format specifiers do, except for `%c` and a few others. Anyway, I compiled your code with gcc and was unable to reproduce the double iteration behavior. What input caused it to iterate twice in your experiments?

Comment: @AndreyT: I didn't know `%d` skips white-space internally, that's one keyboard press saved! Well, it seems I was mistaken assuming it runs twice. It works fine when I provide a numeric input. If I input a non-numeric character (specifically at the `printf("%s", q)` line), I get `q` printed out twice. That seems to be the only the problem so far ..

Comment: @Amr Ayman: Well, as I said above, your code is deliberately written to print `q` twice per iteration on incorrect input. If this is a problem, why are you doing that?

Comment: @AndreyT: Oh yes, I was testing the function without a loop and it seems I forgot to remove that ! Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Note: Looks incorrect to use type `size_t` for min/max limits on `int num`.  Using `int min, int max` makes more sense, unless there is some unposted rational for `size_t`.  Further, using the unsigned type `size_t min/max` in `(*num > max || *num < min)` will make  `*num` act as if it was `unsigned`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you print `q` twice per iteration: once at the beginning and then again after the error message. This might create an illusion of the cycle iterating twice per input, while in reality it does not happen. In my experiments I could not reproduce this double-iteration.

Also, the space before `%d` in `scanf(" %d", num)` is redundant. It is not an error and it will make `scanf` to skip any leading whitespace, but `%d` already skips leading whitespace internally by itself.